# how to crop video with camera effect [ffmpeg]

Tags: ffmpeg, camera, crop, effect

I use this code

```
crop=in_w/2:in_h/2:(in_w-out_w)/2+((in_w-out_w)/2)*sin(t*10):(in_h-out_h)/2 +((in_h-out_h)/2)*sin(t*13)
```

but Screen moves too fast

This is my idea please help me million thanks

[image]

Comment: Decrease the multipliers inside the `sin` i.e. `sin(t*0.5)`. Your image isn't clear. What's the position supposed to be at t=0, t=2m and t=5m ?

Comment: thank Mulvya. 

t from 00:00 to 00:02 minute - video input will crop at "top" "quarter" "left"

t from 00:02 to 00:05 minute - video input will crop at "top" "quarter" "right"

sory my eng not good.

Comment: So, no motion needed?

Comment: can you Adjust x y coordinate in a circle.

    (in_w-out_w)/2+((in_w-out_w)/2)*sin(t*10):(in_h-out_h)/2 +((in_h-out_h)/2)*sin(t*13)

Comment: Yeah, use same sin periods and coefficient multipliers for both x and y i.e.  `(in_w-out_w)/2+((in_w-out_w)/2)*sin(t*2):(in_h-out_h)/2 +((in_w-out_w)/2)*sin(t*2)`

Comment: thank you so much. i see <3